# Como pegar a soma de uma coluna inteira no SQLSERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server, query, sum

Eu preciso pegar o valor total do campo VOL (imagem abaixo), ele já é gerado pela função SUM. Pode ser em uma outra query.  É necessário todas as dízimas periódicas.

ex: total = VOL(7,6890028) -> soma das 4 linhas da coluna VOL

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não está claro sua dúvida, precisa detalhar mais

Comment: Tira o `GROUP BY`. Se você quer somar todos, não tem porque ter discriminando o `Volumes`.

Comment: quero a soma de todas as linhas da coluna VOL

Comment: Mas você está agrupando pelo `Volumes`, não tem lógica o que você está dizendo. Você quer somar todos, e repetir no campo `VOL`, sendo que agrupa por `Volumes`. Está errado seu conceito, ou não está clara a dúvida.

Comment: Tente GROUP BY CUBE (NF.VOLUMES)

Comment: @Motta mesmo com CUBE ou ROLLUP, acho que não foi essa a ideia dela. Mas, vou esperar mais detalhes.

Comment: primeiro eu listo Vol de cada nota fiscal(cada linha é uma nota).
Mas agora eu preciso do total geral (soma do volumes de todas as notas).  Pode ser em outra query.

Comment: @Motta - deu certo... Isso mesmo... Obrigada "Tente GROUP BY CUBE (NF.VOLUMES)"

Comment: @Motta coloque na resposta que eu marco como a certa

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Algo como :

```
Select campo1,
       sum(valor1) valor
from tabela
group by cube (campo1)
```

Comment: cube () --- isso ai

Comment: Para outras funções úteis pesquise por "analytic functions" https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer algo nesse sentido

```
Select sum(a.VOL) from ( 
    *SUA QUERY AQUI*) a
```

Comment: deu errado a soma, "15,3780056" quando deveria dá "7,6890028"

Comment: Parece que está somando duas vezes. Não ficou alguma múltiplicação indevida na tua query?